# Task Scheduler's idle settings

Tags: scheduled-tasks

I want a Windows 10 Task Scheduler trigger to run a batch file that puts the computer to sleep at 8:10 AM of each day only if the computer has been idle for 1 hour. And here is my settings:

[image]

[image]
[image]

Problem is, if the computer ceases to be idle prior to 8:10 AM, then the computer goes to sleep if it gets to be idle for even a couple of minutes. I thought setting “Do not wait” for “Wait for idle for” is to deliberately combat this very behavior.

Thanks

Comment: Please add a screenshot for the Settings tab. Note that Task Scheduler service only checks every 15 minutes, so is likely to be launched up to 15 minutes before 8:10 or 15 minutes after. So the question is how much before 8:10 the computer ceases to be idle.

Comment: Added the screenshot

Comment: Question: How much before 8:10 does the computer cease to be idle?

Comment: Anywhere between zero to an hour.

Comment: Even if you continue using the PC, when it's been idle for like maybe 10 minutes, goes to sleep.